# Table Alignment Is Not Working

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm not sure why my the content in my table is not aligning to the left. Here is a picture: [image] I want the word 'second' to be sitting over to the left. Here is my HTML:

```
<section>
<p>Test Number 6 </p>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="statusBlank"></td>
        <td>second</td>
        <td>0000-00-00 00:00:00</td>
        <td class="tightcell"><a href="#">Download</a>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="statusBlank"></td>
        <td>second</td>
        <td>0000-00-00 00:00:00</td>
        <td class="tightcell"><a href="#">Download</a>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="statusBlank"></td>
        <td>second</td>
        <td>0000-00-00 00:00:00</td>
        <td class="tightcell"><a href="#">Download</a>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="statusBlank"></td>
        <td>second</td>
        <td>0000-00-00 00:00:00</td>
        <td class="tightcell"><a href="#">Download</a>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

  <p>Final Project </p>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td class="statusBlank"></td>
        <td>second</td>
        <td>0000-00-00 00:00:00</td>
        <td class="tightcell"><a href="#">Download</a>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="statusBlank"></td>
        <td>second</td>
        <td>0000-00-00 00:00:00</td>
        <td class="tightcell"><a href="#">Download</a>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>
```

Here is my SCSS (I'm using Sass):

```
/* ----TABLE---- */
section {
  @include grid-row();
}
section p {
  @include grid-column(12);
  font-family: $font-stack;
  font-size: 23px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
 }
.button {
  font-family: $font-stack;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: $secondary-color;
  height: 27px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 7px;
  margin: 6px 0 5px 0;
  padding: 5px 7px 5px 7px;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: $primary-color;
}
table {
  @include grid-column(12);
  padding: 0;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  text-align:right;      
  border-collapse:separate;
  border-spacing: 0 2px;
}
table {
  tr {
    background: #fff;
  }
  tr:hover {
    background: #EBF7FC;
  }
  tr td {
    padding:6px 8px;
  }
  tr td:first-child {
    border-left: 3px solid #fff;
  }
  tr td:last-child {
    border-right:3px solid #fff;
  } 
  tr:hover td:first-child {
    border-left: 3px solid $secondary-color;
  }
  tr:hover td:last-child {
    border-right:3px solid $secondary-color;
  } 
}
.status {
  color:#fff;
  width: 33px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.statusRunning {
  background-color: #5AD427;
  @extend .status;
}
  .statusQueued {
  background-color: #A4E786;
  @extend .status;
}
  .statusIncomplete {
  background-color: #FFCC00;
  @extend .status;
}
.statusBlank { 
}
table tr td:nth-child(2) {
  text-align:left; 
}
.tightcell a {
 margin-right:25px;
 color: $secondary-color;
}
```

What am I not seeing here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `.statusBlank` rule has no content, just set the width of this column (can be 0px) and you'll see how the second one will get aligned to the left:

```
.statusBlank { 
   width: 15px
}
```

Comment: That's true.  But will it make enough of a difference?  He hasn't set the width of the cells.

Comment: Kind of, because by default will be 25% to each one, and you can see in the picture, there's no much content. I'll add your suggestion to my answer.

Comment: I'd never trust the browser to figure out the cell widths... they always tend to be all over the place, especially if wider content pushes them outwards.

Comment: You're right. Thanks for the info, Now i won't trust in browsers anymore :(

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I've tried messing with the rule you pointed out, but I can't seem to get the word 'second' to align all the way to the left. Can you help?

Comment: Thanks! I've thought more about what I really need and made a new thread. Could you take a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920728/how-to-only-make-a-css-element-appear-on-one-page